# Rails3 + link_to(..., :remote => true) + IE 6/7 does not work

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, ruby-on-rails-3

I get this strange error if I use a link_to with the :remote => true parameter in IE 6 and IE 7. IE 8 and all other browsers works just fine:

[image: IE7 bug]

If I commenting out the code for the link (jQuery binding on ajax:success), the error still appears. I don't know how to locate/track this error, because line 1529... does not exists. What is going wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the jQuery `data()` function to store stuf into DOM elements. IE doesn't support this at all.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data

> Note that this method currently does not provide cross-platform support for setting data on XML documents, as Internet Explorer does not allow data to be attached via expando properties.